# Beginners question regarding ElGamal

Tags: elgamal-encryption

How to motivate, that in ElGamal Alice the recipient keeps her keys fixed, while Bob the sender changes the key each time - why not both of them change their keys each time?

Comment: And also, what is the difference between ephemeral-static ElGamal and DHE? Looks the same to me.

Comment: How would you be able to trust that the changed key is indeed the key of Alice? An adversary could simply replace that key in the protocol by his / her own. If you have a way to trust the *ephemeral* keys then the scheme would be possible, but that may require another *static* key...